# how do I make this code print the unique words in the file in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, alphabetical-sort

```py
# Ask for inputs

fileName = input("Please enter the filename: ")

f = open(fileName, 'r')
lines = f.read()
f.close()
 
#Input the text, find unique words and add to a list

words = []
wordList =  lines.split()

for word in wordList:
    if word not in words:
    words.append(word)
    words.sort()

print("words in aphabetical order are: ")
    
def main():
    fileName = input("Enter the input file name: ")
   
sorted_words_file(fileName)
   
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Comment: You don't need to be sorting `words` on every iteration through `wordList`. More efficient to take it outside the loop and sort once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for.

```
from string import whitespace

def sorted_words_file(fileName):
    # Read the text, find unique words and add to a list
    f = open(fileName, 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    f.close()
    wordList =  lines.split()

    # Remove surrounding whitespace and drop empty strings (if any)
    wordList = [w.strip(whitespace) for w in wordList if w.strip(whitespace)]

    # Get unique words and sort them
    words = sorted(list(set(wordList)))

    print("words in aphabetical order are:", words)

def main():
    # Ask for inputs
    fileName = input("Enter the input file name: ")
    sorted_words_file(fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that capitalization matters when sorting, with words starting with lowercase letters coming after capitalized words. If you don't care for that, just put a `.lower()` to the clean-up, list comprehension line.

Answer (score 0):

Given the filename the whole thing is a one liner :

```
sorted(list(set(open(filename, "r").read().split())))
```